# Возможно ли узнать, находится ли окно в состоянии "сворачивание", "разворачивание"?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-10

Существует ли какой-либо способ узнать, является ли данное окно в Windows 7/10 в состоянии "разворачивания" или "сворачивания"?

Суть в том, что если включены эффекты рабочего стола (Aero в Windows 7), у окон при сворачивании и разворачивании есть определённая анимация. Однако если нажать по свёрнутому окну в task bar, и сразу же вызвать `IsWindowVisible()` на этом окне, Win32API скажет нам, что окно уже открыто, но по факту оно будет видимым лишь через N миллисекунд (когда анимация разворачивания закончится).

Я пробовал найти API, который позволит узнавать о таких вещах, но, к сожалению, не нашёл решений.

P.S.: Я знаю, что можно поставить `global hooks` (и написать DLL-ку, в которые поставить `handlers`) на подобные `actions`, но это слишком тяжёлый и неэлегантный хак получится.

**UPD.**
Полноценного решения исходной проблемы, к сожалению, так и не нашёл. Так что на текущий момент просто использую workaround -- на необходимое время отключаю эффекты анимации (и только их), создавая временный объект, который на деструкторе восстанавливает анимации (если они были до этого включены пользователем).

```
pub struct AnimationDisabler {
    info: ANIMATIONINFO,
}

pub fn disable_animation() -> Option<AnimationDisabler> {
    let mut animation_info = ANIMATIONINFO {
        cbSize: mem::size_of::<ANIMATIONINFO>() as UINT,
        iMinAnimate: 0
    };
    unsafe { SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETANIMATION,
                                                mem::size_of::<ANIMATIONINFO>() as UINT,
                                                &mut animation_info as LPANIMATIONINFO as LPVOID,
                                                0) };


    // Animation is disabled already
    if animation_info.iMinAnimate == 0 {
        return None
    }

    let mut animation_disabled = ANIMATIONINFO {
        cbSize: mem::size_of::<ANIMATIONINFO>() as UINT,
        iMinAnimate: 0
    };

    unsafe { SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETANIMATION,
                                                    mem::size_of::<ANIMATIONINFO>() as UINT,
                                                    &mut animation_disabled as LPANIMATIONINFO as LPVOID,
                                                    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE) };

    return Some(AnimationDisabler { info: animation_info });
}

impl Drop for AnimationDisabler {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETANIMATION,
                                                    mem::size_of::<ANIMATIONINFO>() as UINT,
                                                    &mut self.info as LPANIMATIONINFO as LPVOID,
                                                    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE) };
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1052913/276994

Comment: Если так мешает эта анимация и если я не ошибаюсь то её можно убрать, а если не мешает и просто нужно отследить это событие - то можно как вариант "чекать" размер окна.

Comment: и еще [вот сюда можно глянуть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Duracell, да, я убираю анимацию, использую это как workaround, но, в идеале, с анимацией решение тоже должно быть работать. Поллить размер окна не помогает, WinAPI репортит правильный (полный) размер окна как только пользователь клацнул по окну в task bar. Сейчас мне приходится поллить состояния окон с частотой 60 Hz и делать всякие хаки c расчётом предполагаемого времени через steady clock. Но это больше костыли, чем элегантное решение.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за ссылку, я уже пробовал этот подход, он позволяет определить включена ли анимация (и\или отключить её), но, к сожалению, не даёт значение времени анимации в случае, если она включена.

Comment: @Programmer, а там вроде какой-то параметр таймаут можно получить? я не смотрел глубоко, но может это как-то можно привести к _времени работы_ анимации?

Comment: @Grundy, к сожалению я такой функциональности там не нашёл. Да, там есть структура ANIMATIONINFO, которую заполняет эта функция, если запросить информацию о том, включена ли анимация. Но никакое поле структуры ANIMATIONINFO не даёт информцаии о том, какова длительность этой анимации (хоть там и int значение для одного из полей, но оно всегда равно единице, когда анимация включена.

Comment: может можно посмотреть в сторону [windows animation api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd317017(v=vs.85).aspx)? у меня так и не дошли руки проверить подойдет оттуда что-нибудь или нет

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, Вам нужно использовать [WM_SIZING message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) или [WM_SIZE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx).

> **WM_SIZING**
>    Sent to a window that the user is resizing. By processing this message, an application can monitor the size and position of the drag rectangle and, if needed, change its size or position.
>
> **WM_SIZE**
>    Sent to a window after its size has changed.

Пример использования

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
     {
         // ...
        case WM_SIZE:
            {
                //...
            }
        case WM_SIZING:
            {
                //...
            }
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Это можно сделать только для своих окон, я не могу отлавливать сообщения, которые посылаются другим окнам, принадлежащим не мне, unless я установлю global hooks. Последний подход тоже пробовался, но это "тяжёлая артиллерия" и создаёт очень много усложнений и проблем. Иными словами, я знаю, что проблему можно было бы решить через глобальные хуки, но это скорее большой хак, который, к тому же, добавляет много проблем и affects всю систему по сути.

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет `GetWindowRect` ? Вернет ноль - значит окно свернуто )

Comment: а что вернет, если окно _в процессе_ разворачивания?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, но я, к сожалению, не знаю на него ответа. Я надеялся, что эта функция не будет использоваться как "самостоятельная единица" - а как-то поможет решению задачи. Возможно, если сделать серию вызовов - то это что-то даст. Как считаете ?

Comment: @Grundy, если окно в процессе разворачивания, GetWindowRect() возвращает полный размер окна как если бы оно уже развернулось.

Comment: Значит, серия вызовов не поможет )

Comment: @isnullxbh, сейчас я и делаю похожую серию хаков, делаю постоянный полинг состояния окна и его геометрии и считаю timestamps между апдейтами, дальше сверяю их с предполагаемым временем анимации и таким образом фильтрую информацию, но это потребляет больше CPU и требует постоянный поллинг visibility окна и его геометрии.